# How do I move tooltip text on a link?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, text, hyperlink, tooltip

I am quite a beginner with D3.
Currently I am working on a network graph without force. Now I have a problem with showing tooltips when hovering over a link. The desired text shows up, but is always in the upper left corner.

This is how I create the links so far:

```
        rect.data.links = [
            {"source":0,"target":1, "distance":100, "weight": 4, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":1,"target":2, "distance":100, "weight": 12, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":1,"target":3, "distance":100, "weight": 4, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":2,"target":0, "distance": 100, "weight": 9, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":2,"target":4, "distance": 100, "weight": 6, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":0,"target":4, "distance": 100, "weight": 12, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":3,"target":0, "distance": 100, "weight": 12, "color" : "black"},
            {"source":3,"target":2, "distance": 100, "weight": 9, "color" : "black"}

        ];

        // Initialize the links
        var links = rect.svg
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(rect.data.links)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:g")
            .attr("class", "link");

        links
            .append("line")
            .attr("x1", function(l) {
                var sourceNode = rect.data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                    return i == l.source
                })[0];
                d3.select(this).attr("y1", sourceNode.y);
                return sourceNode.x
            })
            .attr("x2", function(l) {
                var targetNode = rect.data.nodes.filter(function(d, i) {
                    return i == l.target
                })[0];
                d3.select(this).attr("y2", targetNode.y);
                return targetNode.x
            })
            .style('stroke', function (d) {
                return d.color;
                }
            )
            .style('stroke-width', function(d) {
                return Math.sqrt(d.weight);
            })
            .on("mouseover", function() {
                return tooltip_links.style("visibility", "visible");})
            .on("mouseout", function() {
                return tooltip_links.style("visibility", "hidden");
            });


        // create a tooltip with keywords
        var keywords = links
        .append("foreignObject")
            .data(rect.data.links)
            .attr("width", "170px")
            .attr("height", "75px")
            .attr("x", d => ((d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2))
            .attr("y", d => ((d.source.y + d.target.y) / 2));


        // create a tooltip
        var tooltip_links = keywords
            .append("xhtml:div")
            .style("position", "absolute")
            .style("visibility", "visible")
            .text("Lorem ipsum");
```

This is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9facu458/

How can I force the link tooltip to be on the link?

[image: The image shows the content of console.log(e)]

Comment: EDIT: None of it worked properly so I chose to use vis.js instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (will work for D3 v3/v4):

```
tooltip_links
  .style('left', `${d3.event.offsetX}px`)
  .style('top', `${d3.event.offsetY}px`)
  .style('visibility', 'visible');
```

Note that your fiddle gets stuck all the time, please fix it.

UPDATE: For D3 v6, use:

```
tooltip_links
  .style('left', e => `${e.offsetX}px`)
  .style('top', e => `${e.offsetY}px`)
  .style('visibility', 'visible');
```

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me an error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetX' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetY' of null

Comment: Which version of d3 you use? Do you have import * as d3 from 'd3'?

Comment: I use v3, imported from https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js
It seems like v3 does not have something like "event"? Should I use a newer version of D3?
EDIT: I chose to use v6 now, still can not get it to work.

Comment: You definitely use v6 (v6.min.js), which is the latest. Take the updated part of the answer and mark it as correct if it helps

Comment: It did not help, the text is still stuck on the upper left corner when hovering over any link. Could you please explain what e means in the updated answer?

Comment: 'e' means event. You can print it to the console: e => console.log(e), and see its data

Comment: There is no e.offsetX and e.offsetY to be found in the log.

Comment: Please share your console screenshot